# Difference between Javascript new FormData and HTML form with (form).serializeArray()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data

It seems like the Newly added `FormData` class in Javascript is getting rampant on line. Mostly when targeting multiple file uploads with Ajax. But some how it has some compatibility issues with most of IE if not 10+...

Should I have an HTML like:

```
<form id="normalForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmmit="gaga()">

<input name="aFile" id="aFile" type="file" multiple/>

<input type="button" value="go">

</form>
```

and the normal javaScript:

```
function gaga {

var f= document.getElementById("normalForm");
/// do something
}
```

or the a function with the New *FormData:*

```
 function nGaga (){

    var f= new FormData()
        f.append("aFile", fileInputElement.files[0])

/// and whatever else to be appended

    }
```

After going through some reading, i somehow learnt that, this is mostly used to generate `"Key:value"` object in Javascript. However, using jQuery, I could do somethinglike:

```
var f= $('#normalForm').serializeArray();
```

This will kinda give me the `"Key:value"` object.

So, why should one use the `new FormData` while dealing with XMLHTTPrequests despite it's issues? and what is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say for instance that you wanted to upload a PDF but also needed to include some user generated metadata along with it as JSON or XML (or anything really). With [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) not only can we upload [Files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) and strings (which is already possible with HTML forms) but we can also upload [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) which allow us to upload dynamically generated content and be able to specify the content-type:

```
document.getElementById('dropzone').ondrop = function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  uploadFiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
};

function uploadFiles(files) {
  var nextId = 123;
  var xml = "<a id=\"a\"><b id=\"b\">hey!<\/b><\/a>";
  var json = {
    title: "Hello World!",
    tags: ["pdf", "non-fiction", "literature"],
    token: "ABCeasyAs123"
  };

  files.forEach(function(file, i) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    json.id = nextId + i;

    formData.append("XML",  new Blob([ xml ], { type: "text/xml" });
    formData.append("JSON", new Blob([ JSON.stringify(json) ], { type: "application/json" }));
    formData.append("PDF",  file);

    xhr.open("POST", "/upload");
    xhr.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
      if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var progress = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
        console.log('Upload #%d is %d% complete.', i+1, progress);
      }
    }
    xhr.send(formData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Clear...I can see the Use now... Now what's gonna happen to solve issues with browser compatibilities?... anyWorkAround for IE earlier versions than 10?

Comment: @ErickBest You're basically SOL when it comes to IE<10 support. The only possible solution would be to use Flash to handle the uploads (which probably isn't ideal).